# Android Firebase stores custom object members with alphabet keys (e.g. "a", "b", "c") only when installed via a release apk

Tags: android, firebase

For most of the classes, this works okay, but for one in particular, I'm getting this result after calling setValue() with the object, where the correctly-named keys are added in as well. This confuses the listener I have set on this location and causes strange behavior. Doesn't seem to happen with any other class though, and for whatever reason it *only* happens when I install a release apk. Works fine (normal key names) when debugging.

```
"stats":{
  "a" : 0,
  "b" : 0,
  "c" : 0,
  "d" : 0,
  "e" : 0,
  "hp" : 5,
  "level" : 1,
  "maxHp" : 5,
  "xp" : 0
}
```

PlayerStats.class

```
public class PlayerStats implements Serializable {

    public static final int START_MAX_HP = 5;

    public int gold;
    public int level;
    public int xp;
    public int hp;
    public int maxHp;

    public PlayerStats() {}

    public PlayerStats(int gold, int level, int xp, int hp, int maxHp) {
        this.gold = gold;
        this.level = level;
        this.xp = xp;
        this.hp = hp;
        this.maxHp = maxHp;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates what the next xp threshold is to level up for the player based on their level
     * @param level The player's level
     * @return xp required to reach the next level
     */
    public static int getNextXpGoal(int level) {
        int x = level + level - 1;
        return (int) (x * Math.log((double)x) * 10 + 100);
    }

    public int getGold() {
        return gold;
    }

    public int getMaxHp() {
        return maxHp;
    }

    public int getHp() {
        return hp;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public int getXp() {
        return xp;
    }
}
```

Snippet that causes the result above:

```
// Update player stats
    final DatabaseReference statsRef = ref.child("users").child(uid).child("stats");
    statsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                PlayerStats stats = dataSnapshot.getValue(PlayerStats.class);
                int hpLost = FailQuestAsyncTask.calculateHpLost(stats.hp, quest.difficulty);
                stats.hp -= hpLost;

                // Save new stats
                statsRef.setValue(stats);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I haven't been able to find any evidence that this has happened to anyone else.

**Edit:** I figured out why I was getting the weird result above. I was directly setting members of "stats" instead of passing a new object in one method. However, I'm still interested in why Firebase uses this alphabetical naming scheme when running the release apk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running Proguard on your release builds? It may be modifying the class names, which are then being used to write to the database. Look for something in your build.gradle like:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}
```

You can add Proguard rules in your project's Proguard file to prevent the models being modified, replacing the package name with your own model package:

```
# Add this global rule
-keepattributes Signature

# This rule will properly ProGuard all the model classes in
# the package com.yourcompany.models. Modify to fit the structure
# of your app.
-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** {
  *;
}
```

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard) for more details.

Comment: Indeed, this was the case. Variable names are normal now. Thanks!