# Firebase Database child creation problem (with Model)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I would like to register the name and surname of the users in the database as an example using a model. The data is stored in the database, but does not send the names I use in the model as child names. Instead, it saves "a, b, c, d ..." What is the reason of this?

> **Created database:**

```
"-LMqLmS09gGKjR-s9CML" : {
  "a" : "Robin",
  "b" : "Hood"
}
```

> **The database I want to create:**

```
 "-LMqLmS09gGKjR-s9CML" : {
      "firstname" : "Robin",
      "lastname" : "Hood"
    }
```

> User.java (Model):

```
public class User {

    public String fistname;
    public String lastnname;

    public User(String fistname, String lastnname) {
        this.fistname = fistname;
        this.lastnname = lastnname;
    }

    public String getFistname() {
        return fistname;
    }

    public void setFistname(String fistname) {
        this.fistname = fistname;
    }

    public String getLastnname() {
        return lastnname;
    }

    public void setLastnname(String lastnname) {
        this.lastnname = lastnname;
    }
}
```

> MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String firstname="Robin";
String lastname="Hood";
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        String key = mDatabase.push().getKey();

        User users = new User(firstname,lastname);

        mDatabase.child(key).setValue(users);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. It's because I used proguard for security. Proguard shuffles the code you type so that other people cannot see the code after creating the .APK. Firebase was automatically classified because it also confused the names of the child. I solved the problem by leaving the model classes out of the proguard.

[Android Firebase stores custom object members with alphabet keys (e.g. "a", "b", "c") only when installed via a release apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376800/android-firebase-stores-custom-object-members-with-alphabet-keys-e-g-a-b)